# What is CGinterpolationquality?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, camera

I've implemented a camera into my app and I wanted to know what CGinterpolationquality is. There isn't much documentation on what it does.

Comment: ive seen lines like CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmap, kCGInterpolationHigh) used with scaling. working with low quality could end up being faster but leave those compression / scaling type artifacts...it's up to the type of program or dev what's best to use

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [`CGContext` Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html):

> Returns the current level of interpolation quality for a graphics context.
>
> Interpolation quality is a graphics state parameter that provides a hint for the level of quality to use for image interpolation (for example, when scaling the image). Not all contexts support all interpolation quality levels.

Furthermore...

> CGInterpolationQuality
>
> Levels of interpolation quality for rendering an image.

```
enum CGInterpolationQuality {
   kCGInterpolationDefault = 0,
   kCGInterpolationNone = 1,
   kCGInterpolationLow = 2,
   kCGInterpolationMedium = 4,
   kCGInterpolationHigh = 3
};
typedef enum CGInterpolationQuality CGInterpolationQuality;
```

> `kCGInterpolationDefault`: The default level of quality.
>
> `kCGInterpolationNone`: No interpolation.
>
> `kCGInterpolationLow`: A low level of interpolation quality. This setting may speed up image rendering.
>
> `kCGInterpolationMedium`: A medium level of interpolation quality. This setting is slower than the low setting but faster than the high setting.
>
> `kCGInterpolationHigh`: A high level of interpolation quality. This setting may slow down image rendering.

Comment: In short, if you have an image and you display it on the screen not with its original size, `CGInterpolationQuality` controls how the scaling is done [better means slower, of course]